# Game Development. I'm creating a draw stack. How should I design it? Details after the jump

Tags: python-2.7, game-engine

what I mean by draw stack is actually a holding structure that will hold if certain items are present by id and a boolean valued array and draw them to the screen if they are.

How would I design this object to hold values that represent the item... and a range of indexes that represent predetermined types(a kind of reserve) that could go on infinitely.
Like 1 or -1 = the display screen 0-9 = special objects like console screen etc. 10-1000 = players 1001-5000 = npcs...

and how would I do a value system that would represent if they are active on the draw stack... and if they aren't.

Comment: Could you please tell us what your final goals are and *why* you think you need that data structure? Sounds like an interesting problem, but I'm not sure if I understand what you want to do.

Comment: I'm trying to make an object that can see if drawable-to-screen objects are present and if are draw them to the screen.

Comment: Hmm, I think I'd probably just give the drawable objects a `drawable` attribute and then loop through the container (list, sprite group, etc.) and check `if hasattr(gameobject, 'drawable'): # draw it`. Or alternatively put the drawable objects into one container and the other objects into a non-drawable container. I'd still like to hear more about the details. Why do you need to put everything into one container?

Comment: Well I'm trying to make a simple game engine for learning purposes. So i thought it would be a good idea to make a way to add drawable objects to a stack and if they were present draw them. I guess that takes up extra processor power though. Was just looking for good design ideas to make it. I'm beginning to think its just a waste of cpu power as I'm on an old netbook.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I don't have experience with engine design, so I'm afraid I can't help you much. I think modern engines like [Godot](https://godotengine.org/) usually use trees to store and access the game objects. Here's a very basic overview of its [scene tree](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/step_by_step/scene_tree.html). You probably have to look at the C++ source code to really understand how it works. Another interesting topic to research would be "entity component systems".